# End-user Documentation Generation

Tags: 7

Is there a way to automatically generate end-user documentation (likely in a stubbed or skeletal format) for content types that you have setup?

Perhaps there is a module that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has an API for [documentation and comment standards](https://drupal.org/node/1354) that allow you embed comments in the code using a special syntax that will automatically generate documentation for the module, including modules that create content types.

This is the system that is used to automatically generate the online [API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal)  found on http://api.drupal.org and other similar sites.

The API module used to generate these pages parses documentation and code in PHP files, and it expects documentation to be in a format similar to other code/documentation parsing systems such as PHPDoc, JavaDoc, etc. The system was originally based on [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), but it has evolved into something that has its own set of tags and Drupal-specific functionality.